# div only showing up when debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I got a piece of code which drives me insane.
I am loading some Data from the server which takes some time, therefore I would like to display a "loading-icon". But the icon is not showing up, so I debugged the code in Chrome and then it is working.

```
$(".k-loading-mask").show(); 
//loading the data from the server
var purchaseInvoiceItems = getOpenPurchaseInvoiceItems(id);
viewmodel.Items = ko.mapping.fromJS(purchaseInvoiceItems, {}, viewmodel.Items);

var prepaymentableOrders = getPrepaymentableOrders(id);
viewmodel.PrepaymentableOrders = ko.mapping.fromJS(prepaymentableOrders, {}, viewmodel.PrepaymentableOrders);
//loading done... hide the loading-icon.
$("div.k-loading-mask").hide();
```

**EDIT:**

```
function getOpenPurchaseInvoiceItems(id) {
    var result = jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/purchaseinvoices/getopenpurchaseinvoiceitems',
        data: JSON.stringify({ supplierId: id }),
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
    var json = result.responseText;
    var purchaseInvoiceItems = eval("(" + json + ")");
    return purchaseInvoiceItems;
}

function getPrepaymentableOrders(id) {
    var result = jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/purchaseinvoices/getprepaymentableorders',
        data: JSON.stringify({ supplierId: id }),
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
    var json = result.responseText;
    var purchaseInvoiceItems = eval("(" + json + ")");
    return purchaseInvoiceItems;
}
```

**EDIT2**

After refactoring the calls to async ajax I ran into the problem, that the `done()` of `getOpenPurchaseInvoiceItems` is never called. The `done()` of `getPrepaymentableOrders` is called when I call the function directly.
But Chrome Networkanalysis tells me the networktransaction is finished after ~3 seconds.
Maris answer is also not working for me, `done()` is never called.

```
function getOpenPurchaseInvoiceItems(id) {
    $(".k-loading-mask").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/purchaseinvoices/getopenpurchaseinvoiceitems',
        data: JSON.stringify({ supplierId: id }),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json"
    }).done(function (data) { //This done is never called.
        viewmodel.Items = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewmodel.Items);
        getPrepaymentableOrders(id);
    });
}

//This one works like a charm when called directly
function getPrepaymentableOrders(id) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/purchaseinvoices/getprepaymentableorders',
        data: JSON.stringify({ supplierId: id }),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
    }).done(function (data) {
        viewmodel.PrepaymentableOrders = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewmodel.PrepaymentableOrders);
        $("div.k-loading-mask").hide();
    });
}
```

**EDIT 3** 
Added an error-callback, which actually gets fired.

> status 200
>   statusText OK
>   responseText (The Json of the result-items)

I don't quiet get why the result has an error ...

**Fun-Fact**:
This works, and it seems that my predecessor had the same problems, because this code is a modified version of my predecessors code.

```
.error(function (data) {
    var json = data.responseText;
    var purchaseInvoiceItems = eval("(" + json + ")");
    viewmodel.Items = ko.mapping.fromJS(purchaseInvoiceItems, {}, viewmodel.Items);
    getPrepaymentableOrders(id);
});
```

Seems like the result cannot be parsed directly?!

**Fiddler Response**

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
>   Date: Mon, 28 Sep 2015 11:29:15 GMT
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
>   Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: 126537
>   Connection: Close
>
> [{"GoodsReceiptItemId":311360,"PurchaseOrderNumber":"BE0010018","SupplierProductNumber":"205.00-122","ProductNumber":"205.00-122","SupplierDeliveryNumber":"5503","GoodsReceiptDate":new Date(1442527200000),"Description":"001-4631-00, \"L-A-EE\"","ShouldBePayed":false,"Amount":500.00000,"Price":2.66000,"PriceUnit":1.00000,"TotalPrice":1330.00000,"PurchaseOrderId":309360,"ProductId":4792,"GoodsReceiptId":299080,"Id":0,"HasBeenSaved":false,"Errors":{"Errors":[],"HasAnyError":false,"HasSumError":false},....]

Comment: show the code for getOpenPurchaseInvoiceItems and getPrepaymentableOrders.

Comment: It is not, `getOpenPurchaseInvoiceItems` and `getPrepaymentableOrders`  are synchron ajax calls

Comment: synchronous ajax call freezes the browser; hence no loading animation.

Comment: But the icon `.show()` is called before the functioncall is made and it is showing up when I am debugging the code.

Comment: @Altoyr but UI has no time to be updated, you could use e.g: `$("div.k-loading-mask").hide(400);`

Comment: yes..thats true that you have called `.show()` before your helper function calls. But this is how browser behaves. UI rendering threads gets blocked by synchronous Ajax Call; so you don't see any change on UI. Even mouse hover CSS effect doesn't work if sync calls are getting executed. I will suggest to go for Async calls and UI fresh will happen side by side.

Comment: Show div in 'beforeSend()' and hide in 'Complete()'

Comment: try having  a `error` callback implemented to check if any error got caught . you can also try `hiding` the `div` in `compete` callback (`var J = $.ajax({})` and  `j.complete(functon(){//hide})` ) .

Comment: @Altoyr does any error appear in debugger console?

Comment: No error is displayed in the console, it seems as JS is not able to parse the result directly as JSON (see my last edit)

Comment: Yes, it is most likely that what is being served by the server is not valid JSON.

Comment: It is interesting, that the resultText in `error()` is parseable.

Comment: @Altoyr what `contentType` does response have?

Comment: Response Content-Type is `application/json`

Comment: Can you attach the `raw` of server response(you can find it in fiddler)? I think that something wrong on the backend...

Comment: Added the response, but not all of the data because the response are >100 objects.

Comment: @Altoyr Error is here in JSON:

`"GoodsReceiptDate": newDate(1442527200000)` - it is not valid JSON property. I see that you use asp.net mvc as backend. Just try to use different serializer for `DateTime`.

So thats why your jquery fails on JSON.parse and you run into `fail` callback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90793/discussion-between-altoyr-and-maris).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in the javascript there is only one thread and you are running sync calls to the api, UI is getting freezed until the requests is done. That is why you don't see the loading bar at all. So, you have to use async calls and promises to achieve what you want.

The next code should work.

```
function getOpenPurchaseInvoiceItems(id) {
   return $.post('/purchaseinvoices/getopenpurchaseinvoiceitems', { supplierId: id });
}

function getPrepaymentableOrders(id) {
    return $.post('/purchaseinvoices/getprepaymentableorders', { supplierId: id });
}


$(".k-loading-mask").show(); 
//loading the data from the server
var purchaseInvoiceItemsPromise = getOpenPurchaseInvoiceItems(id);
var prepaymentableOrdersPromise = getPrepaymentableOrders(id);
$.when(purchaseInvoiceItemsPromise, prepaymentableOrdersPromise ).done(function(purchaseInvoiceItems, prepaymentableOrders){
   viewmodel.Items = ko.mapping.fromJS(purchaseInvoiceItems, {}, viewmodel.Items);
   viewmodel.PrepaymentableOrders = ko.mapping.fromJS(prepaymentableOrders, {}, viewmodel.PrepaymentableOrders);
   $("div.k-loading-mask").hide();
})
```

**Never use the synchronous ajax calls. If you for some reason want to use synchronous calls then you definitely doing something wrong.**

Comment: This is not working for me, please see my second edit.

Comment: @Altoyr some details about why it is not working? Does it shows some errors?

Comment: As stated in my second edit, the done is not called.
If I refactor my code to use synchron calls the done is not called either. No errors... :(

Comment: It could be a server error as a result of which the response is not sent and "done" is not called.
Can you make sure that the response arrives without any errors (HTTP 200)? You can use Fiddler to view network activity.

Comment: Just use google chrome network to see the response from the endpoints. The only reason when promise doesn't call done callbacks is that something wrong with the endpoint(or wrong url)... Just make sure that 200 status code arrived.

Answer (score 1):

Try using asynchronous calls, like so:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/purchaseinvoices/getopenpurchaseinvoiceitems',
        data: JSON.stringify({ supplierId: id }),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json"
    }).done(function(purchaseInvoiceItems){
      //.....
    })
```

PS: never use "eval". If you're getting JSON, and the headers say that it's JSON, jquery is smart enough to transform the result to the actual object.
If however you need to convert a JSON string to object, use JSON.parse